# htaccess and mod_rewrite causing apache to fail with a missing file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a simple php site, I want to have friendly URLs. So I would like my urls to look like:

http://mysite.com/page/123

Which points to:

http://mysite.com/page.php?id=123

And this works! But If I point to a file that isn't on the server, apache spikes, and I have to force Apache to quit (developing locally with MAMP, for right now).

Here's my .htaccess file. Any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)/?([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [N,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: apache doesn't like it when files that it requires don't exist.  It won't even start up if I specify error log files that don't exist in my vhosts.

Comment: It makes me grumpy, too, but missing files are a fac of life. Is there a way for apache to behave correctly? Why isn't the 404 rule kicking in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the order of your two rules and use the *L* flag instead of *N*:

```
RewriteCond $1 !.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)/?([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that causes a redirect loop? [Sat Jan 29 02:53:48 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I needed!